# Are single element lists allowed in perl?

Tags: ajax, list, perl, catalyst

I'm trying to dynamically create a list of values from an AJAX request (using Catalyst), like this:

```
my @listofvalues         = @{$params->{parameter_with_many_values}};
```

Then I loop through the list to make database insertions (one for each value). Since I need to loop through various lists like the one above, I need to access the index of the list. I am currently doing it like this:

```
foreach my $key (0 .. $#listofvalues){
  $table_model->new({
    field1                => $listofvalues[$key],
    field2                => $x,
    field3                => $another_listofvalues[$key]
    field4                => $yet_another_listofvalues[$key]
  });
}
```

This seems to work fine when **two or more** elements are received in the request. Whenever a single element is received, I get an error like

```
[error] Caught exception in pbitdb::Controller::Subjects->add "Can't use string ("1") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at /home/lioneluranl/svn/pbitdb/pbitdb/script/../lib/pbitdb/Controller/Subjects.pm line 119."
```

Where, in this case, **1** is the value received and **line 119** is the line where @listofvalues is being declared.

Now I've tried several to workaround this issue, but haven't found anything that works both ways (for a single or for various values). Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is with whatever code is setting `$params->{parameter_with_many_values}`. It's ending up as a literal string "1".

Comment: There's a comma missing before `field4`.

Comment: That means that $params->{parameter_with_many_values} does not contain a reference to an array. It contain the scalar value "1".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, single element lists are OK in Perl, as are arrays and references to such arrays.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

sub new {
    print Dumper \@_;
}

my $table_model = 'main';

for my $values ( [ 'a' .. 'c' ],
                 [ 'd' ]
) {
    my $params = { parameter_with_many_values => $values };
    my @listofvalues = @{ $params->{parameter_with_many_values} };
    my @another_listofvalues = map uc, @listofvalues;

    for my $key (0 .. $#listofvalues) {
        my $x = rand;
        $table_model->new({
            field1 => $listofvalues[$key],
            field2 => $x,
            field3 => $another_listofvalues[$key]
        });
    }
}
```

How do you populate `$params->{parameter_with_many_values}`?

### Update

It seems [Catalyst::Request](http://p3rl.org/Catalyst::Request) should mention that their "safe" parameters should be handled as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

for my $params ( { param_with_many_values => 'a' },
                 { param_with_many_values => [ 'a' .. 'e' ] },
                 { something => 'else' }
) {
    my $value_or_values = $params->{param_with_many_values};
    my @list_of_values = ref $value_or_values     ? @$value_or_values
                       : defined $value_or_values ? $value_or_values
                                                  : ();
    print Dumper \@list_of_values;
}
```

Comment: Population comes from Catalyst::Request perl module and unfortunately that's the way it works (meaning that a given paramater could either be a scalar or an array depending on how many inputs carry the same name in the form). Didn't try mapping but seems like a good workaround. Lemme test...

Comment: Oh, it seems you need `my $value_or_values = $params->{param_with_many_values}; my @list_of_values = ref $value_or_values ? @$value_or_values : $value_or_values;` and you need to check the value exists at all to prevent `undef` creeping into the array.

Comment: I just did that and was about to post the answer. That worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you are asking about arrays (a type of variable), not lists (a vague term which can take on numerous definitions, none of which are pertinent here).

Yes, you can have an array with only one element.

```
$ perl -e'my @a = "ele"; CORE::say 0+@a; CORE::say for @a;'
1
ele
```

That's not the problem. The problem is that

```
@{$params->{parameter_with_many_values}}
```

expects

```
$params->{parameter_with_many_values}
```

to contain a reference to an array, but it contains `1` instead. It was probably set using

```
$params->{parameter_with_many_values} = @a;   # Assigns number of elements
```

instead of

```
$params->{parameter_with_many_values} = \@a;
```

Comment: Yes to all above. Unfortunately I can't change the module that processes the requests, but I'll post the workaround once I got it. Thanks for the input :)